# "food to cook" meaning

Tags: grammar, meaning

> She spends the next hour and a half preparing *food to cook*. From 6:30 to 8:30, she cooks.

Does *food to cook* equal *food which is to be cooked*. What's the grammar? Any other examples?

Answer (score 1):

This is a **nonfinite relative clause**. Yes, "food to cook" means "food that is to be cooked". For some discussion, see these two Wikipedia sections: [Nonfinite relative clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses#Nonfinite_relative_clauses) and [*To*-infinitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms#To-infinitive) (scroll down to the "As a relative clause" portion).

There are many examples:

> This is the place to be.
>
> I have homework to do.
>
> It was a sight to see.